# Patching and running a python library as a build tool in bazel

Tags: python, bazel, patch

I'm new to bazel and am currently writing a build for a C++ library with some python build tool dependencies. It currently uses `WORKSPACE` rather than Bzlmod.

How would I go about implementing the python build tool for this 4 step build process?

1. Install python library dependencies from `pip` or GitHub
2. Patch the `foo` package with `.patch` diff files generated by `git`
3. Run `foo/bar/baz.py`, one of a few build tools embedded in this python package, to preprocess the C++ code to generate some output source files
4. Build the C++ library using these files

---

I have tried a variety of approaches and am currently able to call `foo/bar/baz.py` after installing its dependencies. I've hit a few stumbling blocks:

1. It seems that I may need to write a `foo_BUILD` file because there is a runtime error when performing a relative import (`from . import qux`) because no parent package is found. I am looking into using `entry_point()` to resolve this.
2. I'm not sure how to apply the patch when using `rules_python` to install the tool. If I use `http_archive` or `py_repository`, I can use their `patches` arguments with the caveat that no files are found while attempting to patch a relative path, but it may be related to the working directory
3. It seems like it's necessary to manually create a `requirements_lock.txt` file and call `bazel run //:requirements.update` *before* attempting a build, which is not ideal. Is there a way to dynamically generate and build with this file?
4. `foo` doesn't contain an entry point, so `run_binary` returns "ERROR: Cannot run target `//:foo_patched`"

---

### Files

#### WORKSPACE

```
# Clone rules_python for rules to install pip and build python packages
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")

http_archive(
    name = "rules_python",
    url = "https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_python/releases/download/0.20.0/rules_python-0.20.0.tar.gz",
    sha256 = "a644da969b6824cc87f8fe7b18101a8a6c57da5db39caa6566ec6109f37d2141",
    strip_prefix = "rules_python-0.20.0",
)

load("@rules_python//python:repositories.bzl", "py_repositories")

py_repositories()

# Get a known version of the python toolchain
load("@rules_python//python:repositories.bzl", "python_register_toolchains")

python_register_toolchains(
    name = "python3_10",
    python_version = "3.10",
)

load("@python3_10//:defs.bzl", "interpreter")

# Create a repo containing pip packages
load("@rules_python//python:pip.bzl", "pip_parse")

pip_parse(
    name = "pip",
    requirements_lock = "//:patch/requirements.txt",
    python_interpreter_target = interpreter,
)

# Install pip dependencies into the repository
load("@pip//:requirements.bzl", "install_deps")

install_deps()
```

#### BUILD

```
load("@rules_python//python:defs.bzl", "py_binary")
load("@rules_python//python:pip.bzl", "compile_pip_requirements")
load("@cst_pip//:requirements.bzl", "requirement")

compile_pip_requirements(
    name = "requirements",
    extra_args = ["--allow-unsafe"],
    requirements_in = "//:patch/requirements.in",  # "foo == *"
    requirements_txt = "//:patch/requirements.txt",  # Contains foo's transitive dependencies
)

alias(
    name = "baz",
    actual = entry_point("foo")
)

load("@bazel_skylib//rules:run_binary.bzl", "run_binary")
run_binary(
    name = "foo_patched",
    tool = "foo",
    srcs = [requirement("foo")],
    env = {},  # Some environment variables needed
    args = [],  # Many args
    outs = [],  # Some files
```

#### baz.patch

```
--- baz_alpha_bak.py 2000-02-20 20:20:20.000000000 -0000
+++ /site-packages/foo/bar/baz_alpha.py 2020-02-20 20:20:20.000000000 -0000
@@ -10,10 +10,10 @@
# Diff text of the source file
```